# Instrument fail to run GUI test script in real iOS device from Xcode 4.4

Tags: ios, xcode, instruments

I have an UI automation script which run perfectly fine before I update Xcode to 4.4.
But after I update Xcode to 4.4, instrument hang after 2nd run on actual iOS device (runs ok on simulator).

Anybody have the same problem and found any work around?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the same behavior.  You don't even need a script.  All you need to do is start your app with Instruments, stop recording and attempt to start recording again.  I have seen this with XCode 4.4 and 4.4.1 while running the app on iPads with 5.0.1 and 5.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem.

Here is the solution:

I moved xcode 4.3.2 to trash and had only xcode 4.4.1 installed on my machine.

This works like a gem.